# How to get a notify email with file attatchment , whenever we place new file in shared location?

Tags: java, excel, eclipse, networking, ftp

I will explain my requirement here.
We have shared location in Network(like http://emea.com/ABC/Files), Every month some other team folks  will place some excel sheet in that location. we manully check that location and pick up that file. 
**Requirement is** :- whenever A new file will place in that location we need to get email automatically with the latest file attached.

How can i achieve  this in java , or do we have any open source tools for this ,
Please share your thoughts on this :)

Comment: Yes you can do this is java

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html